# Customise selected/unselected background of Switch composable in Jetpack Compose?

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, android-compose-switch

I am using a Switch Composable for which I want to give a custom background for selected and unselected state. How can I do that?

```
var switchState by remember { mutableStateOf(false) }

Switch(
   checked = switchState,
   onCheckedChange = { switchState = !switchState }                          
)
```

Answer (score 16):

You can customize the colors of the thumb and the truck using the **`colors`** attribute. If you want to customize also the background you can use the `background` modifier.

Something like:

```
var switchState by remember { mutableStateOf(false) }

Switch(
    checked = switchState,
    onCheckedChange = { switchState = !switchState },
    colors  = SwitchDefaults.colors(
        checkedThumbColor = Teal200,
        checkedTrackColor = Teal200,
        uncheckedThumbColor = Yellow,
        uncheckedTrackColor= Yellow,
    ),
    modifier = Modifier.background(if (switchState) Blue else Red )
)
```

[image][image]